# Custom max and min scale in seaborn 2d kde plot

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, kernel-density

I have csv data which contain detection of people in particular day and in particular hour(i.e. from 7pm to 12pm). I am trying to display 2d kernel density estimation plot using seaborn library. 
**Problem** is, when I try to draw 2d-kde on particular hour (i.e. from 7pm to 8pm), it draw kde according to points occur between particular hour (i.e. 7pm and 8pm) and assign color accordingly, and this color vary from hour to hour. 
 
[image: 2D-KDE plot for 10pm]

In above picture this plot show kde for 10pm.

[image: 2D-KDE for 8pm]

Above is 2d-kde plot for 8pm.

**Required Result** My requirement is that color of kde plot should be consistence along different hour.